# AVG with LIMIT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, conditional-statements

I'm looking to make a SQL query, but I can't do it... and I can't find an example like mine.

**I have a simple table People with 3 columns, 7 records :**

[image: Table People Image]

**I'd like to get for each team, the average points of 2 bests people.**

**My Query:**

```
SELECT team
     , (SELECT AVG(point) 
          FROM People t2 
         WHERE t1.team = t2.team 
         ORDER 
            BY point DESC 
         LIMIT 2) as avg 
  FROM People t1 
 GROUP 
    BY team
```

**Current result:** (average on all people of each team)

[image: Current Result Image]

Apparently, it's not possible to use a limit into subquery. "ORDER BY point DESC LIMIT 2" is ignored.

**Result expected:**

[image: Result Expected Image]

**I want the average points of 2 bests people (with highest points) for each team, not the average points of all people of each team.**

How can I do that? If anyone has any idea..

I'm on MySQL Database

Link of Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c80ef/1

Thanks !

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images or links to them.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please post your code as actual text content and not as image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

try to make a order number by a subquery, which `order by point` desc.

then only get top 2 row by each team, if you want to get other `top` number just modify the number in `where` clause.

```
CREATE TABLE `People` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `team` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `point` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `People` (`id`, `name`, `team`, `point`) VALUES
(1, 'Luc', 'Jupiter', 10),
(2, 'Marie', 'Saturn', 0),
(3, 'Hubert', 'Saturn', 0),
(4, 'Albert', 'Jupiter', 50),
(5, 'Lucy', 'Jupiter', 50),
(6, 'William', 'Saturn', 20),
(7, 'Zeus', 'Saturn', 40);

ALTER TABLE `People`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `People`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT team,avg(point) totle
FROM People t1 
where (
      select count(*) 
      from People t2
      where t2.id >= t1.id and t1.team = t2.team
      order by t2.point desc
  ) <=2  ## if you want to get other `top` number just modify this number
group by team
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c80ef/34/0)**:

```
|    team | totle |
|---------|-------|
| Jupiter |    50 |
|  Saturn |    30 |
```

Comment: It's really perfect ! Thank you very much D-Shih ! Thank you all for your remarks

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain in MySQL.  If you want the two highest *point* values, you can do:

```
SELECT p.team, AVG(p2.point)
FROM people p
WHERE p.point >= (SELECT DISTINCT p2.point
                  FROM people p2
                  WHERE p2.team = p.team
                  ORDER BY p2.point DESC
                  LIMIT 1, 1  -- get the second one
                 );
```

Ties make this tricky, and your question isn't clear on what to do about them.